# Getting a Day from Date in Perl

Tags: perl

Is there a way to find out day of the week when provided a date. How would I code this in Perl?

For example

Given 02-02-2016(dd-mm-yyyy) outputs Friday
Note: Without using any modules.

Comment: See Date::Manip (http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.53/lib/Date/Manip.pod)

Comment: 02-02-2016 day is Tues day

Comment: @Christopher Ok without module it is possible. What have tried so far.?

Comment: The input format always like that `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Comment: If you want a mathematical way of determining the day of week number, ( which you could then use to subscript into an array of day names ) look up John Conway's Doomsday Algorithm.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers - Why would you recommend a horrible old module like Date::Manip when Time::Piece is included with Perl?

Comment: @DaveCross Two reasons. One, I've never considered Date::Manip horrible. Two, I've never heard of Time::Piece before. About 1% the former, 99% the latter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *Note: Without using any modules.*

Calendaring is hard. No, calendaring is REALLY HARD! It's very easy to get wrong. Use a module.

Fortunately there's a built in module to do this, [Time::Piece](http://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).  It has [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) to parse the date into an object.  From there you can ask it a great number of things.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $time = Time::Piece->strptime("02-02-2016", "%d-%m-%Y");
say $time->fullday;
```